# Error:Android Dex: Cannot create classes.dex file

Tags: android

I am receiving Error:Android Dex:  Cannot create classes.dex file error while running my android project in android studio. Is there a solution for this?
i even tried to rebuild the project after deleting the support_v4.jar files.

Comment: Error? Post Stacktrace(or actual error message). You are using Android Studio, do not use the "jar", use the Gradle dependency.

Comment: Try changing the support library from compile to provided.

Comment: Hi, where is that option ?